# shell script set the default numbers as double digit zero as prefix

Tags: shell-script, shell, numeric-data

In a shell script, I'm processing, some addition process will print an output. If it is a single-digit one, then it has to add zero as a prefix.

Here is my current script:

```
c_year=2020
for i in {01..11}
        do  
            n_year=2020
            echo 'Next Year:'$n_year
            if [[ $i == 11 ]]
            then n_month=12
            echo 'Next Month:'$n_month
            else 
            n_month=$(($i + 1))
            echo 'Next Month:'$n_month
            fi
            echo $date" : Processing data '$c_year-$i-01 00:00:00' and '$n_year-$n_month-01 00:00:00'"
        done
```

The `i` value is in doule digit, but the `n_month` is still printing single digit. How do I set default shell output should return as double digit?

Or any alternate way to solve this?

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `echo` - it provides C-style formatting options including field width and padding options ex. `'Next Month:%02d\n' "$n_month"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

typeset -Z2 n_month

c_year=2020
for i in {01..11}
        do
            n_year=2020
            echo 'Next Year:'$n_year
            if [[ $i == 11 ]]
            then n_month=12
            echo 'Next Month:'$n_month
            else
            n_month=$(($i + 1))
            echo 'Next Month:'$n_month
            fi
            echo $date" : Processing data '$c_year-$i-01 00:00:00' and '$n_year-$n_month-01 00:00:00'"
        done
```

But if I'm not mistaken, there are better ways to do date arithmetics in the shell.  Perhaps using "date".